# Create Gatsby Project on a git initialized folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby, netlify

I have a git folder with no files, so i wanted to use the Gatsby CLI to create a project in that folder.
Using `gatsby new .` but failed that the repository is not empty but it only have `.git` folder only.
What alternatives can i use to achieve my objective.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With `gatsby new .` you are setting the name of your project and the starter you want to clone (by default [this one](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default)), in your case, it is an invalid syntax because you are setting neither the name nor the starter so it fails.

From [Gatsby docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/setting-up-gatsby-without-gatsby-new/):

> There are many Enterprise level companies that maintain an internal
> clone of the NPM registry for security purposes. If you work for such
> a company, you may find that you are able to successfully run `npm install -g gatsby-cli` but **cannot run the gatsby new** 
> **as the gatsby new command clones a repo from a public GitHub**
> **repository**. Many companies block public GitHub, which will cause the
> gatsby new command to fail. Not to worry, though, you can set up a new
> Gatsby site without the gatsby new command with a few quick steps.

One easy thing you can do is to create your new project using `gatsby-cli` (like `gatsby new test-project)`, cut all content, and paste it to your desired folder which is linked via `.git` folder to your repository.

Alternatively, you can create your project normally (`gatsby new test-project`) and then start your git (`git init`) and link it to your repository using:

```
git remote add origin remote <repositoryURL>
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push -f origin master
```

More information about adding a remote [here](https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/adding-a-remote).

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to create a gatsby project without using the `new` keyword. For that, in your desired project directory:

- You will have to create an initialized `package.json` file by running `npm init -y`
- then `npm install gatsby react react-dom`
- then create a `index.js` file in `src/pages` directory
- run `gatsby develop`

Now you have a gatsby development server up and running. In this way, you may not have all the configuration that comes with the starter project.

For more information: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/setting-up-gatsby-without-gatsby-new/